# How to validate a custom URL in laravel with protocols specified?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to validate the URL with the specified protocol.

HTTP and HTTPS type validation is not applicable for the below URLs.

1. If the URL is secure the see below.

   `rtmps://username:password@server:port/`
2. Without a secured URL will be as follows.

   `rtmp://server:port/`

I only need validation for the above 2 URL(s) only.

I have tried laravel's URL type validation but it is not validating for these protocols.

Also want to tell you only I am able to use is regex validation, because it is a request class of laravel where I have put the validation rule.
laravel version 6.2

Comment: Have you tried writing your own [custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)?!

Comment: Custom validation with Regex? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: @brombeer, No i have not tried that.

Comment: @Justinas, can you tell me how can i use this regex in laravel's regex.

Comment: You can put your regex in your controller https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this command:

```
`php artisan make:rule ValidateRTMPUrlRule`
```

this command will create a custom rule class

```
`
 <?PHP

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ValidateRTMPUrlRule implements Rule
{
/**
 * Create a new rule instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
   
    $result = parse_url($value);
    $scheme = strtolower($result['scheme']);
    if('rtmp' == $scheme)
    {
        if(isset($result['user']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(isset($result['pass']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    if('rtmps' == $scheme)
    {
        if(!isset($result['user']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!isset($result['pass']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return ':attribute is not a valid RTM protocol url.';
}

}
`
```

then in your request

```
`$data = $request->validate([
        'url' => ['required', new ValidateRTMPUrlRule],
    ]);`
```